# Plot a line between two subplots while handling the zoom with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to be able to draw a line between two subplots in Matplotlib. Currently, I use the method provided in this SO topic: [Drawing lines between two plots in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543359/drawing-lines-between-two-plots-in-matplotlib) thus using transFigure and matplotlib.lines.Line2D

However, when I zoom on my figure (both subplots share the same x and y axes), the line does not update i.e. it keeps the same coordinate in the figure frame but not in my axes frames.

Does it exist a simple way to cope with this?

Comment: By zoom you mean zooming interactively with the tools provided in the matplotlib window or do you mean zooming programmatically?

Comment: With the tool provided in the matplotlib plot toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment in the linked question ([Drawing lines between two plots in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543359/drawing-lines-between-two-plots-in-matplotlib)) suggests, you should use a [`ConnectionPatch`](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#using-connectorpatch) to connect the plots. The good thing about this `ConnectionPatch` is not only that it is easy to realize, but also it will move and zoom together with the data.

Here is an example of how to use it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True) 

x,y = np.arange(23), np.random.randint(0,10, size=23)
x=np.sort(x)
i = 10
ax1.plot(x,y, marker="s", linestyle="-.", c="r")
ax2.plot(x,y, marker="o", linestyle="", c="b")

con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(x[i],y[i]), xyB=(x[i],y[i]), 
                      coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
                      axesA=ax2, axesB=ax1, arrowstyle="-")

ax2.add_artist(con)

plt.show()
```