# Lines across plots to different coordinates in matlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a project, matching image fragments to larger pieces. For example, matching Fragment to Complete in the below image.[image: Figure_1]

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543359/drawing-lines-between-two-plots-in-matplotlib), I am trying to draw a lines across two plots to indicate matching points, with each point having different coordinates.

This is the code that I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import numpy as np

(x1,y1) = (292, 21)
(x2,y2) = (930, 1111)

fig = plt.figure()

a1=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
imgplot = plt.imshow(fragment) #fragment is the name of the first image
a2=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
imgplot = plt.imshow(complete) #complete is the name of the second image

xy1 = (x1,y1)
xy2 = (x2,y2)
con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=xy1, xyB=xy2, coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
                  axesA=a1, axesB=a2, color="red")

a1.add_artist(con)

a1.plot(x1,y1,'ro',markersize=2)
a2.plot(x2,y2,'ro',markersize=2)
plt.show()
```

However, the resulting image comes out with the line going behind the second image (as per below). What do I need to change in my code?

NB: I realise I could be doing this with OpenCV.

[image: Figure_2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543359/drawing-lines-between-two-plots-in-matplotlib)'s answer, you need to provide the second axes as the first argument to the connection patch and add the patch to the second axes, instead of the first one.

```
con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=xy2, xyB=xy1, coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
                  axesA=a2, axesB=a1, color="red")

a2.add_artist(con)
```