# ConnectionPath gets hidden behind subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to mark a line over two aligned subplots. Therefore, I use `matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch` as suggested in other answers. It worked already in other examples, but here for the second time, the line just is cut off at the second plot area.

**How do I assure that the ConnectionPatch is plotted in the front?**

I tried playing around with zorder, but did not find a solution yet.

[image]

```
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xes=[-2, 0, 2]
field=[0, -10, 0]
potential=[-20, 0, 20]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

axs[0].plot(xes, field)
axs[1].plot(xes, potential)

# line over both plots
_, ytop = axs[0].get_ylim()
ybot, _ = axs[1].get_ylim()
n_p_border = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(0., ytop), xyB=(0., ybot), 
                             coordsA='data', coordsB='data',
                             axesA=axs[0], axesB=axs[1], lw=3)
print(n_p_border)
axs[0].add_artist(n_p_border)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to inverse the role of the two axes. This is also shown in [Drawing lines between two plots in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543359/drawing-lines-between-two-plots-in-matplotlib/44023219#44023219).

```
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xes=[-2, 0, 2]
field=[0, -10, 0]
potential=[-20, 0, 20]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

axs[0].plot(xes, field)
axs[1].plot(xes, potential)

# line over both plots
_, ytop = axs[0].get_ylim()
ybot, _ = axs[1].get_ylim()
n_p_border = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(0., ybot), xyB=(0., ytop), 
                             coordsA='data', coordsB='data',
                             axesA=axs[1], axesB=axs[0], lw=3)

axs[1].add_artist(n_p_border)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh so simple. The idea just is to draw the `ConnectionPath` on the last drawn axis. Thanks.