# Drawing arrows between two tables (as an image) (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to make a plot of two tables next to each other with arrows shooting between them in a particular way (in `matplotlib`). So far, I know more or less how to use `plt.arrow` to get the arrows to do what I want, and I found an article that shows how to plot just the table portion of `plt.table`.

https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-little-tables-with-matplotlib-9780ef5d0bc4

Source code, in case the link dies:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
title_text = 'Loss by Disaster'
footer_text = 'June 24, 2020'
fig_background_color = 'skyblue'
fig_border = 'steelblue'
data =  [
            [         'Freeze', 'Wind', 'Flood', 'Quake', 'Hail'],
            [ '5 year',  66386, 174296,   75131,  577908,  32015],
            ['10 year',  58230, 381139,   78045,   99308, 160454],
            ['20 year',  89135,  80552,  152558,  497981, 603535],
            ['30 year',  78415,  81858,  150656,  193263,  69638],
            ['40 year', 139361, 331509,  343164,  781380,  52269],
        ]
# Pop the headers from the data array
column_headers = data.pop(0)
row_headers = [x.pop(0) for x in data]
# Table data needs to be non-numeric text. Format the data
# while I'm at it.
cell_text = []
for row in data:
    cell_text.append([f'{x/1000:1.1f}' for x in row])
# Get some lists of color specs for row and column headers
rcolors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.full(len(row_headers), 0.1))
ccolors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.full(len(column_headers), 0.1))
# Create the figure. Setting a small pad on tight_layout
# seems to better regulate white space. Sometimes experimenting
# with an explicit figsize here can produce better outcome.
plt.figure(linewidth=2,
           edgecolor=fig_border,
           facecolor=fig_background_color,
           tight_layout={'pad':1},
           #figsize=(5,3)
          )
# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=row_headers,
                      rowColours=rcolors,
                      rowLoc='right',
                      colColours=ccolors,
                      colLabels=column_headers,
                      loc='center')
# Scaling is the only influence we have over top and bottom cell padding.
# Make the rows taller (i.e., make cell y scale larger).
the_table.scale(1, 1.5)
# Hide axes
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
# Hide axes border
plt.box(on=None)
# Add title
plt.suptitle(title_text)
# Add footer
plt.figtext(0.95, 0.05, footer_text, horizontalalignment='right', size=6, weight='light')
# Force the figure to update, so backends center objects correctly within the figure.
# Without plt.draw() here, the title will center on the axes and not the figure.
plt.draw()
# Create image. plt.savefig ignores figure edge and face colors, so map them.
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.savefig('pyplot-table-demo.png',
            #bbox='tight',
            edgecolor=fig.get_edgecolor(),
            facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(),
            dpi=150
            )
```

However, I cannot get two tables to plot next to each other and look nice, and the arrow between the two won't go across the two plotting zones.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)


title_text = 'Loss by Disaster'
footer_text = 'June 24, 2020'
fig_background_color = 'skyblue'
fig_border = 'steelblue'
data =  [
            [         'Freeze', 'Wind', 'Flood', 'Quake', 'Hail'],
            [ '5 year',  66386, 174296,   75131,  577908,  32015],
            ['10 year',  58230, 381139,   78045,   99308, 160454],
            ['20 year',  89135,  80552,  152558,  497981, 603535],
            ['30 year',  78415,  81858,  150656,  193263,  69638],
            ['40 year', 139361, 331509,  343164,  781380,  52269],
        ]
# Pop the headers from the data array
column_headers = data.pop(0)
row_headers = [x.pop(0) for x in data]
# Table data needs to be non-numeric text. Format the data
# while I'm at it.
cell_text = []
for row in data:
    cell_text.append([f'{x/1000:1.1f}' for x in row])
# Get some lists of color specs for row and column headers
rcolors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.full(len(row_headers), 0.1))
ccolors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.full(len(column_headers), 0.1))
# Create the figure. Setting a small pad on tight_layout
# seems to better regulate white space. Sometimes experimenting
# with an explicit figsize here can produce better outcome.
# ax1.figure(linewidth=2,
#            edgecolor=fig_border,
#            facecolor=fig_background_color,
#            tight_layout={'pad':1},
#            #figsize=(5,3)
#           )
# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
the_table = ax1.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=row_headers,
                      rowColours=rcolors,
                      rowLoc='right',
                      colColours=ccolors,
                      colLabels=column_headers,
                      loc='center')
# Scaling is the only influence we have over top and bottom cell padding.
# Make the rows taller (i.e., make cell y scale larger).
the_table.scale(1, 1.5)
# Hide axes
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax1.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
#
# Do it again
#
the_table = ax2.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=row_headers,
                      rowColours=rcolors,
                      rowLoc='right',
                      colColours=ccolors,
                      colLabels=column_headers,
                      loc='center')
# Scaling is the only influence we have over top and bottom cell padding.
# Make the rows taller (i.e., make cell y scale larger).
the_table.scale(1, 1.5)
# Hide axes
ax2 = plt.gca()
ax2.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
#
plt.arrow(0.5, 0.5, -5, 1)
```

(The `do it again` could be tidied up with a function, perhaps.)

[image]

Ultimately, I want to get something like the following sketch.

[image]

I am open to minor tweaks to my approach to complete changing what I'm doing and not even using `matplotlib`, but how can I wrangle my idea into some code that will produce something like my sketch?

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there (and perhaps have already solved it in the meantime), the main point missing was that you needed to create an arrow (or rather a `ConnectionPatch`) which needs to transform with the whole figure (i.e. `transform=fig.transFigure`) instead of using only the individual subplots for reference. Note that this solution is [adapted from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44023219/565489) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch) is some relevant documentation.

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,5))

title_text = 'Loss by Disaster'
footer_text = 'June 24, 2020'
fig_background_color = 'skyblue'
fig_border = 'steelblue'
data =  [
            [         'Freeze', 'Wind', 'Flood', 'Quake', 'Hail'],
            [ '5 year',  66386, 174296,   75131,  577908,  32015],
            ['10 year',  58230, 381139,   78045,   99308, 160454],
            ['20 year',  89135,  80552,  152558,  497981, 603535],
            ['30 year',  78415,  81858,  150656,  193263,  69638],
            ['40 year', 139361, 331509,  343164,  781380,  52269],
        ]
# Pop the headers from the data array
column_headers = data.pop(0)
row_headers = [x.pop(0) for x in data]
# Table data needs to be non-numeric text. Format the data
# while I'm at it.
cell_text = []
for row in data:
    cell_text.append([f'{x/1000:1.1f}' for x in row])
# Get some lists of color specs for row and column headers
rcolors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.full(len(row_headers), 0.1))
ccolors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.full(len(column_headers), 0.1))
# Create the figure. Setting a small pad on tight_layout
# seems to better regulate white space. Sometimes experimenting
# with an explicit figsize here can produce better outcome.
# ax1.figure(linewidth=2,
#            edgecolor=fig_border,
#            facecolor=fig_background_color,
#            tight_layout={'pad':1},
#            #figsize=(5,3)
#           )
# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
the_table = ax1.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=row_headers,
                      rowColours=rcolors,
                      rowLoc='right',
                      colColours=ccolors,
                      colLabels=column_headers,
                      loc='center')
# Scaling is the only influence we have over top and bottom cell padding.
# Make the rows taller (i.e., make cell y scale larger).
the_table.scale(1, 1.5)

# Do it again
#
the_table = ax2.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=row_headers,
                      rowColours=rcolors,
                      rowLoc='right',
                      colColours=ccolors,
                      colLabels=column_headers,
                      loc='center')
# Scaling is the only influence we have over top and bottom cell padding.
# Make the rows taller (i.e., make cell y scale larger).
the_table.scale(1, 1.5)

### actually turn axes off:
for a in [ax1,ax2]:
    a.set_axis_off()

con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(0.38,0.4), xyB=(0.43, 0.52), 
                      coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
                      axesA=ax1, axesB=ax2,
                      shrinkA=1, shrinkB=1,
                      ec="red", fc="w", linewidth=2, alpha=1,
                      arrowstyle="-|>",connectionstyle="arc3", 
                      mutation_scale=20, )
ax2.add_artist(con)

plt.show()
```

yields this image:
[image: two tables connected with an arrow]

Note how the arrow start and end points are given in the subplot coordinates (e.g. `(0.38,0.4)`, i.e. you should be able to quickly find good points via mouse hovering.